# which is the unit of work and which is the repository?

Tags: repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have two interfaces and I'm confused about the naming conventions:

```
interface InterfaceA {
    IDbSet<Patient> Patients { get; }
    // others like above
}

interface InterfaceB : InterfaceA {
    int Commit();
}

class DbContext : InterfaceB {
    public IDbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

    int Commit() {
        return this.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I don't want to confuse the other coders on my team. Which interface is the unit of work and which one is the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InterfaceA is the repository.

Reason:

A repository is responsible for persisting data, and InterfaceB has no concept of data to be persisted.